# What does pwdadm -c effect?

Tags: unix, password, user-management, aix

If you were to run pwdadm -c against a user account and it clears the flags from /etc/passwd; what would those cleared flags stop from happening?

Answer (score 2):

Per the man page, here are the flags which `pwdadm -c` might remove:

```
NOCHECK
    Signifies that new passwords need not follow the guidelines 
    established in the /etc/security/user file for password composition. 
ADMIN
    Specifies that password information may be changed only by the
    root user. Only the root user can enable or disable this attribute. 
ADMCHG
    Resets the ADMCHG attribute without changing the user's password.
    This forces the user to change passwords the next time a login
    command or an su command is given for the user. The attribute is 
    cleared when the user specified by the User parameter resets the 
    password.
```